# Cast Function of Mysql is working on NULLIF function of Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL `CAST()` function is not working on output of `NULLIF()` function output. Although both functions are working fine separately.

For this MySQL query:

```
SELECT CAST(NULLIF('2030-01-01', '2012-01-01') AS DATETIME) AS col1, 
  CAST('2030-01-01' AS DATETIME) AS col2, 
  NULLIF('2030-01-01', '2012-01-01') AS col3
```

Output I got is this:

```
col1    col2                  col3
NULL    2030-01-01 00:00:00   2030-01-01
```

For `col1` I was expecting this output "2030-01-01 00:00:00" but I got NULL. You can see that both functions are giving expected result in `col2` and `col3`.

Comment: but if using `IFNULL` in place of `NULLIF`?

Comment: Perhaps you intend `COALESCE()`?

Comment: Could be a bug in MySQL. You could replace `NULLIF(expr1, expr2)` with `CASE WHEN expr1 = expr2 THEN NULL ELSE expr1 END`... they are identical according to the manual.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a [bug in MySQL](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77805); it seems to convert the argument(s) to integer before comparing resulting in the following warning:

```
"Warning"   "1292"  "Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '2030-01-01'"
"Warning"   "1292"  "Incorrect datetime value: '2030'"
```

An alternate solution is to cast the dates *inside* the `NULLIF` function:

```
SELECT NULLIF(CAST('2030-01-01' AS DATETIME), CAST('2012-01-01' AS DATETIME)) -- 2030-01-01 00:00:00
SELECT NULLIF(CAST('2012-01-01' AS DATETIME), CAST('2012-01-01' AS DATETIME)) -- NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

With IFNULL instead of NULLIF it returns your expected result:

```
select CAST(IFNULL('2030-01-01', '2012-01-01') as dateTIme) as col1, CAST('2030-01-01' as datetime) as col2, IFNULL('2030-01-01', '2012-01-01') as col3
```

returns:

```
col1                col2                col3
2030-01-01 00:00:00 2030-01-01 00:00:00 2030-01-01
```

**IFNULL** outputs the second parameter if the first parameter is NULL, otherwise it outputs the first parameter.

**NULLIF** compares 2 values. If BOTH values are equals, it returns NULL otherwise the first parameter.

Comment: You simply cannot change the logic to match the expected result!

Comment: I agree with You